How to Display Special Characters (₹,₤,₿..) in ImGui Window?
I'm working on an application using ImGui for the UI, and I'm having trouble displaying special characters like the Indian Rupee symbol (₹) in my ImGui windows. Currently, these characters are showing up as ? instead of the correct symbols.I'm specifically using OpenGL as the underlying renderer.
Here's what I've done so far:

Loaded a Font: I made sure to load a font that should support special characters.

Replacement Function: I have a function that replaces certain placeholder strings with special characters.


I have a function that replaces certain placeholder strings with special characters, including the Indian Rupee symbol. Here's the function:
  std::string replacedStr = str;
  std::map<std::string, std::string> replacements = {
    {"1397904493", "®"}, {"1397776754", "¶"}, {"1400073811", "§"},
    {"1396991858", "°"}, {"1396929140", "©"}, {"1398041963", "™"},
    {"1397059140", "–"}, {"1397058884", "—"}, {"1397969521", "’"},
    {"1397967985", "‘"}, {"1396986737", "\""}, {"1397969777", "'"},
    {"1397645907", " "}, {"1396984945", "“"}, {"1396986481", "”"},
    {"1396862068", "•"}, {"1397518451", "…"}, {"1398320179", "₹"}
  // Added mapping for the Indian Rupee symbol }; for (const auto &pair
  // : replacements) { size_t pos = replacedStr.find(pair.first); while
  // (pos != std::string::npos) { replacedStr.replace(pos,
  // pair.first.length(), pair.second); pos =
  // replacedStr.find(pair.first, pos + 1); } } return replacedStr; }


Im getting the following result for some special chars  enter image description here
here you can see the code about conversion and rendering methods
enter image description here
or
for (size_t i = 0; i < contents.size();) {
 // Get the Unicode value of the current character and convert it to UTF-8
 uint32_t unicode = workose_studio_getUTF8Unicode(contents, i);
 std::string charStr = utf8::utf32to8(std::u32string(1, unicode));
 std::cout << " charStr :: " << charStr << " unicode :: " << unicode << std::endl;
 // Render the character
 draw_list->AddText(retrievedFont, retrievedFont->FontSize, adjusted_pen_pos, ImGui::GetColorU32(text_color), charStr.c_str(), NULL, 0.0f, NULL);
}

// Console output
// contents :: Char's : ₹ $ £ ¥ € ₠ ₡ ₤ ₥ ₦ ₧ ₨ ₩ ₪ ₫ € ₭ ₮ ₯ ₰ ₱ ₲ ₳ ₴ ₵ ₶ ₷ ₸ ₹ ₺ ₻ ₼ ₽ ₾ ₿
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: C unicode :: 67
// charStr :: h unicode :: 104
// charStr :: a unicode :: 97
// charStr :: r unicode :: 114
// charStr :: ' unicode :: 39
// charStr :: s unicode :: 115
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: : unicode :: 58
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₹ unicode :: 8377
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: $ unicode :: 36
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: £ unicode :: 163
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ¥ unicode :: 165
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: € unicode :: 8364
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₠ unicode :: 8352
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₡ unicode :: 8353
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₤ unicode :: 8356
// charStr :: unicode :: 9
// charStr :: ₥ unicode :: 8357
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₦ unicode :: 8358
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₧ unicode :: 8359
// charStr :: unicode :: 9
// charStr :: ₨ unicode :: 8360
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₩ unicode :: 8361
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₪ unicode :: 8362
// charStr :: unicode :: 9
// charStr :: ₫ unicode :: 8363
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: € unicode :: 8364
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₭ unicode :: 8365
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₮ unicode :: 8366
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₯ unicode :: 8367
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₰ unicode :: 8368
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₱ unicode :: 8369
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₲ unicode :: 8370
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₳ unicode :: 8371
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₴ unicode :: 8372
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₵ unicode :: 8373
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₶ unicode :: 8374
// charStr :: unicode :: 32
// charStr :: ₷ unicode :: 8375

-------------------------------------- Font loading code ---------------------------------------
// Function to load fonts for ImGui in a custom application
void workose_studio_load_fonts()
{
   
    std::string defaultfont = workose_project_root_directory + "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf";

    // Get ImGui input/output configuration
    ImGuiIO &io = ImGui::GetIO();
    ImFontConfig config;

    // Get the default glyph range for the font
    const ImWchar *glyph_ranges = io.Fonts->GetGlyphRangesDefault();

    // Add the default font to ImGui with specified parameters
    ImFont *font = ImGui::GetIO().Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF(
        defaultfont.c_str(),
        18,
        &config,
        glyph_ranges);

    // Store information about the default font
    workose_studio_font_data.font = font;
    workose_studio_font_data.path = defaultfont;

    // Map the default font information to the key "default"
    workose_studio_g_myFonts.fontMap["default"] = workose_studio_font_data;

    // Get the glyph range for Chinese characters
    const ImWchar *glyph_ranges1 = io.Fonts->GetGlyphRangesChineseFull();

    // Initialize an array to store font names
    std::vector<std::string> font_name;

    // Check if layout and element details are available
    if (workose_studio_get_layout_and_element_details.size() > 0)
    {
        // Iterate over layout elements
        for (nlohmann::json::iterator it = workose_studio_get_layout_and_element_details[0][0].begin(); it != workose_studio_get_layout_and_element_details[0][0].end(); ++it)
        {
            nlohmann::json layout_elements = it.value()["layout_elements"];

            // Iterate over layout element details
            for (nlohmann::json::iterator it = layout_elements.begin(); it != layout_elements.end(); ++it)
            {
                std::string element_type = it.value()["LAYOUT_ELEMENT_TYPE"];

                // Check if the element type is "text"
                if (element_type == "text")
                {
                    nlohmann::json paragraphs;
                    // Extract and decode element JSON style attributes
                    std::string element_json_style_attributes = it.value()["ELEMENT_JSON_STYLE_ATTRIBUTES"];
                    std::string decode_data = urldecode(element_json_style_attributes);
                    nlohmann::json json_data = nlohmann::json::parse(decode_data);

                    // Check for the presence of specific style attributes
                    if (json_data.find("frame_style") != json_data.end() && json_data["frame_style"].find("tableDetils") != json_data["frame_style"].end())
                    {

                        // Check if the "tableDetils" field is empty
                        if (json_data["frame_style"]["tableDetils"].empty())
                        {
                            nlohmann::json decoded_json = nlohmann::json::parse(decode_data);
                            // Check for the presence of "paragraphs" in the decoded JSON
                            if (decoded_json.contains("paragraphs"))
                            {
                                paragraphs = decoded_json["paragraphs"];
                                // Store used fonts from paragraphs
                                storeusedfonts(paragraphs);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // table condition
                            const nlohmann::json &frame_style = json_data["frame_style"];
                            // Check for the presence of "tableDetils" in "frame_style"
                            if (frame_style.contains("tableDetils"))
                            {
                                const nlohmann::json &table_details = frame_style["tableDetils"];
                                // Check for the presence of "tableContentArray" in "tableDetils"
                                if (table_details.contains("tableContentArray"))
                                {
                                    const nlohmann::json &table_content_array = table_details["tableContentArray"];
                                    size_t numColumns = table_content_array[std::to_string(0)].size();

                                    // Iterate over table columns and rows
                                    for (size_t x = 0; x < numColumns; ++x)
                                    {
                                        for (size_t j = 0; j < table_content_array.size(); ++j)
                                        {
                                            const nlohmann::json &row_j = table_content_array[std::to_string(j)];

                                            // Check for the presence of the current column in the current row
                                            if (row_j.contains(std::to_string(x)))
                                            {
                                                const nlohmann::json &cell_ij = row_j[std::to_string(x)];

                                                // Check for the presence of "style" in the cell
                                                if (cell_ij.contains("style"))
                                                {
                                                    const nlohmann::json &styleObj = cell_ij["style"];

                                                    // Check for the presence of "paragraphs" in the style
                                                    if (styleObj.contains("paragraphs"))
                                                    {
                                                        paragraphs = styleObj["paragraphs"];
                                                        // Store used fonts from paragraphs
                                                        storeusedfonts(paragraphs);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


It looks like your font does not support these specific characters. It is hard to tell without a [mre] though.

@n.m.couldbeanAI i have used Arial font it does supports for Indian Rupee symbol (₹)

There is still no MRE so it didn't become any easier to identify the problem.

Having said that, all of your characters that are shown correctly belong to the CP-1252 charset (and Latin-1) so perhaps your program is not using UTF-8 at some point.

Are your strings utf-8 encoded? Which compiler are you using? What's your compiler command line?

When loading the font, you can specify which characters to load, and apparently you're not specifying yours there. Also the whole replacement string idea is weird, just use \u20B9 (or \xE2\x82\xB9) for the rupee symbol, and so on.

@n.m.couldbeanAI as you see in the image which i have attached now there i'm getting the symbol and its unicode value  after converting to utf-8

@AlanBirtles Of course utf-8 encoded,  as you see in the image which i have attached now and i'm using clang compiler

Please don't post images of text. I'm not sure how the image shows that the strings are utf8 encoded?

Please do not post images of code. They are worse than useless. Post a [mre] instead. Please pay attention to the minimal requirement. Text replacements are irrelevant so do not include them in your [mre]. Instead, post code that opens a UI and displays a single string. Nothing more.

@n.m.couldbeanAI the program isn't using UTF8 anywhere. The UTF8 string type is std::utf8string, not std::string. std::string may behave like UTF8 if the OS codepage is explicitly set to UTF8.

@vinith what OS are you using and what encoding did you use when you saved the file? Windows for example is natively Unicode since the mid 1990s and more specifically, UTF16, although in the past only the UCS-2 subset was used, that always requires 2 bytes. UTF16 can use more than 2 bytes. The Unicode string types are std::u16string and lately, std::u8string. You'll find legacy code that uses std::wstring too. Unicode literals require a prefix, eg `auto x=u"₹"; for UTF16.

@AlanBirtles ok, i've replaced image by code , by the the function im converting utf 32 to utf8

@PanagiotisKanavos *natively UTF-16

@PanagiotisKanavos Mac OS

@vinith Please edit your question with the code that loads the font, as there is a FAQ entry that explains you must specify which glyph ranges to load

@PanagiotisKanavos Using std::utf8string does not guarantee correct display of UTF8 strings. It is a container of char8_t, nothing more.There is nothing magical in char8_t, it is just another 8 bit character type. It is only needed for overload resolution. Once you pass a bunch of char8_t to an outside library, it is indistinguishable from any other bunch of bytes.

@vinith converting utf 32 to utf8 there are no UTF32 strings in your code. There's no u32string, char32_t or U"xxx" literal, so all are just single-byte characters. The standard way to convert is to use codecvt. A workaround is to use OS functions. You should probably check what actual standard string types

@n.m.couldbeanAI not using the correct type though guarantees mojibake or worse, lost data. In this case, ₹ will be lost because it's not in Latin1. After that, it's up to the OS (I actually remember the transition to Unicode OSs). Windows and MacOS won't have any issues in GUI applications. In terminals, the terminal itself should be set to the correct codepage either through chcp, terminal settings, LC_ALL, LANG or OS settings

@n.m.couldbeanAI I remember one problematic MacBook 7 years ago where the OS and iTerm2 had different LC_ALL settings. It took the IT support guys a while to understand why GUI apps worked, but terminal and iTerm mangled text in different ways

@Botje ya included font loading code

@PanagiotisKanavos "not using the correct type though guarantees" IME the correct type for storing UTF-8 data is std::string. There is no need to use char8_t or std::u8string ever.  OP's problem is with imgui fonts. The default glyph range doesn't contain the required characters. They need to load a custom range, that's all. (The text replacment thing also looks like a problem, but on a different level, unrelated to glyph rendering)

@n.m.couldbeanAI Apple, Microsoft  and the C and C++ communities disagree with you, which is why we have multilingual desktop OSs that can work with German and Cyrillic text at the same time without problem. Never mind the hundreds of SO questions caused by the ambiguity between UTF8 and char/string. The only thing you can say is that the C++ committee took way too long to standardize UTF8 and far too long to get to just UTF16

@PanagiotisKanavos "which is why we have multilingual desktop OSs" I had a multilingual desktop OS at my disposal (more than one actually) that could work with German and Cyrillic text at the same time without problem back in early 2000s. That's way before std::u8string was ever conceived.

@PanagiotisKanavos I don't see a lot of SO questions that can be reasonably answered by "just use std::u8string instead of std::string". Do you? Can you show me one?

@PanagiotisKanavos "committee took way too long to standardize UTF8" Oh but did it ever standardize UTF8? Does std::cout << std::u8string(u8"Hello"); work for you? What does this type solve again? Where would I need to use it?

In applications that need to read 2 files with 2 different codepages, so they can't depend on the ambient codepage. I didn't use German and Cyrillic by accident. There were several R questions (which used std::string on Linux) from German data scientists asking why they couldn't load Polish and Russian data files along with their own. Having specific Unicode types prevents such mixups

@PanagiotisKanavos This doesn't compute. How does having a specific Unicode type prevent you from mixing up non-Unicode types? If you have a UTF-8 type and convert everything you read from files to that type, then you prevent mixups, because everything in your program is UTF-8. But then it doesn't matter which  type you use. We have used char and std::string for that purpose long before i8string. They are our de facto UTF-8 types. If R doesn't keep everything in UTF-8 internally, blame R. Sane languages do, and they don't need std::u8string for that.

The Rupee sign (U+20B9) is not covered by the ImGui default glyph range or the Chinese range. You need to construct a custom glyph range (just pairs of start and stop codepoints) and specify that when loading the font. Same for the other missing glyphs.
The FAQ entry for this has the following examples:
ImVector<ImWchar> ranges;
ImFontGlyphRangesBuilder builder;
builder.AddText("Hello world");                        // Add a string (here "Hello world" contains 7 unique characters)
builder.AddChar(0x20B9);                               // Add a specific character
builder.AddRanges(io.Fonts->GetGlyphRangesJapanese()); // Add one of the default ranges
builder.BuildRanges(&ranges);                          // Build the final result (ordered ranges with all the unique characters submitted)
io.Fonts->AddFontFromFileTTF("myfontfile.ttf", 16.0f, nullptr, ranges.Data);

